# Unzip and read a .gz file from Google Cloud storage via Python (Cloud Function)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, unzip

I have to read an unzip file from google cloud storage in python (cloud function).
I tried below method but the CF crashes everytime.
File in GCS : ABC.gz

```py
import gzip  

def process(data, context):  
    filename = data['name']  
    with gzip.open("'"+filename+"'", 'rb') as f:  
        file_content = f.read()
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Why the GCF crash? Do you have log trace?

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I didn't implement exception handling and thus not able to understand why it was failing. But now I got the real cause and solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. When your function is triggered by a Cloud Storage event you only get the a dictionary containing the [`data`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects) for the event, not the object itself.

You should get the object from Cloud Storage using the `name` and `bucket` from the `data` dictionary. Here's a code that can guide you to get the file which is taken from [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python):

```
import gzip
from google.cloud import storage

def process(data, context):
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(data['bucket'])
    blob = bucket.blob(data['name'])
    blob.download_to_filename("/tmp/" + data['name'])

    #Here goes your code to unzip the file
```

Consider that you may need to add the needed libraries to the `requirements.txt` file and grant the needed permissions to the [Runtime Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account) of the Function to access Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks FerVelvet. It was very helpful. :-)